# I'm new to C++. I'm having error in this code to create a linked list in C++ with the SwapNodes function. The function is not swapping the nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to just change the data of the Node to swap the nodes. Any help is appreciated. Maybe it's a basic mistake i am new to c++.
I know the method to SwapNodes using 4 pointer and that stuff sounds cool, but what's the problem in this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{   

    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(int val)
    {
        data=val;
        next=NULL;
    }
    int Data(){return data;};
    void ChangeData(int newData){data=newData;};
    void setNext(Node *NEXT){next=NEXT;};
    Node *Next(){return next;};
};

class LinkedList
{
    Node *root;
public:
    LinkedList();
    void insert(int pos,int b);
    void deleteNode(int a);
    void outputList();
    void SwapNodes(int x, int y);
    void reverse();
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    root=NULL;
}

void LinkedList::insert(int pos,int b)
{
    Node *temp=root;
    Node *newnode=new Node(b);
    if(pos==0)
    {
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=newnode;
            return;
        }
        newnode->setNext(root);
        root=newnode;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <pos ; ++i)
    {
        temp=temp->Next();
    }
    newnode->setNext(temp->Next());
    temp->setNext(newnode);
}

void LinkedList::deleteNode(int a)
{
    Node *temp=root;
    Node *agla=root->Next();
    if(temp->Data()==a)
    {
        root=root->Next();
        free(temp);
    }
    if(agla->Data()==a)
    {
        temp->setNext(agla->Next());
        free(agla);
        return;
    }
    while(agla!=NULL && agla->Data()!=a)
    {
        temp=agla;
        agla=agla->Next();
    }
    if(agla==NULL)
    {
        cout << "key not found";
    }
    temp->setNext(agla->Next());
    free(agla);

}

void LinkedList::SwapNodes(int x,int y)
{
    Node *temp1=root;
    Node *temp2=root;

    if(x==y)return;
    while(temp1!=NULL && (temp1)->Data()!=x)
    {
        (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
    }
    temp1->ChangeData(y);

    while(temp2!=NULL && (temp2)->Data()!=y)
    {
        (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
    }
    if(temp1==NULL || temp2==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    (temp2)->ChangeData(x);
}

void LinkedList::reverse()
{
    if(root == NULL) return;

    Node *prev = NULL, *current = NULL, *next = NULL;
    current = root;
    while(current != NULL){
        next = current->Next();
        current->setNext(prev);
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    root = prev;
}


void LinkedList::outputList()
{
    Node *temp=root;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout << "empty";
        return;
    }

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<< temp->Data()<< " ";
        temp=temp->Next();
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList newList;
    newList.insert(0,4);
    newList.insert(1,5);
    newList.insert(2,7);
    newList.insert(3,9);
    newList.insert(4,12);
    newList.outputList();
    newList.insert(2,6);
    newList.outputList();
    newList.deleteNode(5);
    newList.outputList();
    newList.SwapNodes(7,9);
    newList.outputList();
    newList.reverse();
    newList.outputList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _I'm having error in this code to create a linked list_ And the error, is?

Comment: What actually ***goes wrong with this***?

Comment: SwapNodes function is not swapping the nodes.

Comment: `(temp1)=(temp1)->Next();` You don't need parenthesis around temp1.

Comment: @KaustubhMundra So, did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger, to see what goes wrong?

Comment: `temp1->ChangeData(y);` What happens if `x` was not found?

Comment: Note that `newList.SwapNodes(9,7);` works as expected given that list.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
void LinkedList::SwapNodes(int x,int y)
{
    Node *temp1=root;
    Node *temp2=root;

    if(x==y)return;
    while((temp1)->Data()!=x)
    {
        (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
    }
    temp1->ChangeData(y);

    while((temp2)->Data()!=y)
    {
        (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
    }
    (temp2)->ChangeData(x);
}
```

You are just undoing the work you already did.

```
while((temp1)->Data()!=x)
{
    (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
}
temp1->ChangeData(y);
```

Is going to find `x` and then set it to `y`.  Then you go to do

```
while((temp2)->Data()!=y)
{
    (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
}
(temp2)->ChangeData(x);
```

Which finds that `y` you just created (as long as there wasn't a previous `y`) and sets it back to `x`.  What you need to do is find the nodes to swap first and then swap their data.  A simple refactor to

```
void LinkedList::SwapNodes(int x,int y)
{
    Node *temp1=root;
    Node *temp2=root;

    if(x==y)return;
    while((temp1)->Data()!=x)
    {
        (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
    }
    while((temp2)->Data()!=y)
    {
        (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
    }
    temp1->ChangeData(y);
    (temp2)->ChangeData(x);
}
```

Should work.  You also should add add error handling code in case `x` or `y` does no exist.

---

Not sure why you are using the parentheses everywhere but

```
(temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
```

Can just be written as

```
temp1 = temp1->Next();
```

Comment: @KaustubhMundra No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: @KaustubhMundra I strongly recommend you add end of list detection  before continuing. It will make the debugging much easier if you don't have this omission hanging over your head.

Comment: And i used parenthesis because i tried doing something by changing temp to Node** that's why, then reverted it back :)

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding, @KaustubhMundra . I meant to say change your source code, not to change the code in the question. It's a bad idea to change the code in the question to match (or in this case partially match) the answers because it damages the flow of logic that lead to the answers. Future readers will have trouble matching the old answers to the new code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while((temp1)->Data()!=x)
    {
        (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
    }
    temp1->ChangeData(y);
```

Loops until it finds a link valued at `x`. Then overwrites the value with `y`. OK. But now you have two `y`s in the linked list, so odds are decent that

```
     while((temp2)->Data()!=y)
    {
        (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
    }
    (temp2)->ChangeData(x);
```

will simply find the `Node` that which was `x` and change it back to `x`.

```
    while((temp1)->Data()!=x)
    {
        (temp1)=(temp1)->Next();
    }
    while((temp2)->Data()!=y)
    {
        (temp2)=(temp2)->Next();
    }
    temp1->ChangeData(y);
    temp2->ChangeData(x);
```

Will prevent that by finding both `x` and `y` nodes before updating their value, but has other problems. Not the least of which is what happens when you hit the end of the list without finding `x` or `y`?

I'd rethink the linking logic because there doesn't seem to be any way to tell that you've hit the end of the list. Typical solution are to set `next` for the last `Node` to `NULL` or `nullptr` and test with something like

```
while(temp1 != nullptr)
```